# Partner Ledger Report using ORM methods in Odoo8

Tags: python-2.7, orm, odoo-8

I am working on partner ledger report and i have prepared report using SQL query

```
def lines(self, partner):
    move_state = ['draft','posted']
    if self.target_move == 'posted':
        move_state = ['posted']

    full_account = []
    if self.reconcil:
        RECONCILE_TAG = " "
    else:
        RECONCILE_TAG = "AND l.reconcile_id IS NULL"
    self.cr.execute(
        "SELECT l.id, l.date, j.code, acc.code as a_code, acc.name as a_name,inv.state,inv.date_due, l.ref, m.name as move_name, l.name, l.debit, l.credit, l.amount_currency,l.currency_id, c.symbol AS currency_code " \
        "FROM account_move_line l " \
        "LEFT JOIN account_journal j " \
            "ON (l.journal_id = j.id) " \
        "LEFT JOIN account_account acc " \
            "ON (l.account_id = acc.id) " \
        "LEFT JOIN res_currency c ON (l.currency_id=c.id)" \
        "LEFT JOIN account_move m ON (m.id=l.move_id)" \
        "LEFT JOIN account_invoice inv ON (inv.move_id = l.move_id)" \
        "WHERE l.partner_id = %s " \
            "AND l.account_id IN %s AND " + self.query +" " \
            "AND m.state IN %s " \
            " " + RECONCILE_TAG + " "\
            "ORDER BY l.date",
            (partner.id, tuple(self.account_ids), tuple(move_state)))


    res = self.cr.dictfetchall()
    sum = 0.0
    if self.initial_balance:
        sum = self.init_bal_sum
    for r in res:
        sum += r['debit'] - r['credit']
        r['progress'] = sum
        full_account.append(r)


    return full_account
```

My result are accurate 
but now I want to do this using ORM methods and code for this:

```
account_move_model = self.pool.get('account.move.line')
    full_account_custom = []
    move_line_ids = account_move_model.search(self.cr, self.uid, [
        ('partner_id', '=', partner.id), ('account_id', 'in', tuple(self.account_ids)),
        ('state', 'in', tuple(move_state))
    ])      
    move_lines = account_move_model.browse(self.cr, self.uid, move_line_ids)

    sum = 0.0
    if self.initial_balance:
        sum = self.init_bal_sum
    for r in move_lines:
        sum += r['debit'] - r['credit']
        r['progress'] = sum
        full_account_custom.append(r)
    return full_account_custom
```

By doing this I am just getting the sum of all invoices of a partner/customer but the list of all invoice is not showing.
Where is the mistake and how to resolve it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using ORM methods there are some difficulties..
Easy way is to use raw query.

Comment: Yes , its difficult using ORM method. Query is the best way to do it